# Inwall splicing armored cable

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to remove this outlet altogether, not even have a junction box, using an inwall splice. I remember that worked well once but with regular NM (AKA "Romex") cable, and this is armored. Considering the cladding is metal, is there a terminal you can use to sheath the edges of where the cladding is cut, to prevent possible sharp edge cutting into the insulation of the wire itself? Similar to the clamp connector you can see where the cable joins the box.

[image]

Or can I just use a little plastic red insert, which looks like it may come off without a terminal/connector to clamp it in place

Comment: What "little plastic red insert" are you referring to? I've only ever seen an in-wall "repair splice" for Romex-type cable. Does such a thing exist which is code-legal for the BX/MC or whatever it is you have there?

Comment: @brhans OP is referring to the little red bushings used with armored cable where it enters a junction box. But that doesn't solve the problem of "in wall splice".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact that is correct

Answer (score 4):

Sensible folks learn to live with junction box covers, or actual receptacles; but there is a way to get what you want.

Since nobody makes a listed in-wall splice for concealed use for BX/AC/MC the only way to get what you want is to remove both of the bits leading to this point (all the way to their present termination points) and replace them with a single cable that is unbroken.

If there are not other receptacles within 12 feet of each other on either side of this (if an unbroken wall) or there's no other receptacle on this section of wall (if longer than 2 feet) removing the receptacle is very probably a code violation.

*But why is this a code violation? Association of long distances to reach receptacles with extension cords and resulting fires. As usual, Code is Written in Blood...*

Comment: I moved a radiator to be right in front of this box, this is why it has to go away. I cannot replace both of the cables coming into this box because I don't have access to the other end, which is why it has to be an in-wall splice of the existing cable ends

Comment: there are other outlets within 12 ft and others on the same wall, so there would be no violation there

Comment: can I just use a NM splice? I mean I understand the code doesn't like it but is it a viable alternative ? what if I just used a clamp connector tightened so that the red bushing doesn't come out?

Comment: I have outlets behind radiators in my house. Local inspector doesn't seem bothered by it. And behind the radiator nobody will see it. Close it up and call it good, or remove the outlet, make the connection in the box, put a blank face plate on the box, paint it to match your wall and call it good. Don't introduce complications you really don't need.

Comment: No, you can't use an NM splice on anything other than NM cable."Code doesn't like it" and "non-viable" are the same thing. You choose to move the radiator here, you choose to rip open enough wall to either replace the whole cable, or to put one or two junction boxes where are **are permanently accessible.** Two is often easiest - go above, or below or to the side as needed.

Comment: @amphibient -- why can't you have a blank JB behind the radiator?

Comment: If you're worried about the heat, @amphibient, use a metal cover plate. If you're worried about the looks, well, it's _behind_ the radiator, so it's unlikely anyone will see it, but you could still paint over it. Some paint will almost _guarantee_ nobody will be able to see it. _Can_ you do this? Sure, it's your house, you can break the rules. Just be sure you're prepared to live (or, possibly, die) with the consequences...

Comment: @amphibient you need to have receptacles within 12' of each other, not within 12' of this location. If you have (for example) a receptacle, then an 8' gap, then this receptacle, then another 8' gap, then another receptacle, and you remove this receptacle, you'll be left with a 16' gap between receptacles.

Comment: I am not getting it inspected

Comment: @Ecnerwal "Code doesn't like it" and "non-viable" are NOT the same thing. [the map is not the territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation). you assume people who write code are some kind of god whereas they've been wrong countless times.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel because of my objective to minimalist aesthetics. I simply don't want a JB there

Comment: @brhans removing this box does not pose any of those violations.

Comment: Would a junction box being behind a radiator be thought of being accessible?  My thought is that radiators are usually not that movable without tools.

Comment: Also, is it 12' from each other as a crow flies or going along the wall?

Comment: If you're going to pull an illegal move anyway, burying an all-metal junction box with a metal cover (which only requires buying the metal cover and Wagos or Wirenuts you trust to Never, Ever, Fail) is arguably less boneheaded (while still illegal/non-compliant) than using a romex splice on armored cable. Leaving the box exposed but non-accessible due to the radiator is smarter yet, but still non-compliant as I understand it.